# How do I combine the object being flattened with the flattened objects using Stream.flatmap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of the following class:

```
class A {
    Stream<B> bs;
}
```

and I want to convert it to a stream of the following class:

```
class AB {
    A a;
    B b;
    AB(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I can see that `flatMap` will give me a stream of B:

```
astream.flatMap(a -> a.bs);
```

but I can't figure out how to pass the a object through to a map like:

```
astream.flatMap(a -> a.bs).map(b -> new AB(a, b));
```

If I try this I get an error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

which I sort of expected.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example.

Comment: Actually having `Stream` saved in field seems really questionable idea to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map the `B`s of the `bs` `Stream` to `AB`s using `map` :

```
List<AB> abs = astream.flatMap(a -> a.bs.map(b->new AB(a,b)))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```